# Can snake deposit venom while drinking?

Tags: snake

When a venomous snake drinks, does it deposit even trace amounts of venom into water?

I understand that "drinking" and "biting"(attacking) involve different reflexes and muscle complexes, so it would probably not be "natural" for a snake to deposit venom while drinking, so the question is probably more about the "hermeticity" of the venom sacs/glands - does venom seep out.

Thank you.